# send GPS coordinates from OEM GPS module to server

Tags: module, embedded, gps

I am looking for information on sending GPS coordinates from a GPS module to a server. How would I go about doing this?

I have done countless google searches on the subject and all searches fail to reveal any information on how the data generated from the GPS unit might be actually sent from the gps module to a server.

There are obvious ways to do this using a GSM deivce, but I can't find any information on low cost data plans, networks, etc

All I would need to do is occasionally send the GPS coordinates from the module to a server. This would be done several times a day. One device would probably have bandwidth of a couple KB per month, that's it. What options are out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need:

1. A GSM modem that support whatever frequencies / technology your intended cellular provider uses.  Bunch of examples here: http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/66 Make sure the module manages the TCP/IP aspects and has an easy interface (AT commands).
2. A data only account with that cell provider for each device.  200MB a month is like $15-20 from most carriers in the US
3. The GPS Module.  Examples here: http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/4
4. A microcontroller to manage the GPS and the cell modem.  Arduino is probably the easiest one to get started with.

Answer (score 0):

All GPS receiver modules output serial NMEA data.  Which is fairly simple to parse, and from there you can do whatever you like with it, store it send it, plot it, etc.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I am talking about how I would send this to a server. Using GSM ?